# .PrintOut in Vba - Code is printing before .pagesetup

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small piece of vba code that copies the data in a pivot table into a new workbook and then is supposed to set up the page so that it fits onto 1 page width wise. However the code seems to be printing then doing the setup. so what should be 2 pages turns into 12.

Its probably just the ordering of my code being wrong - I'm still learning VBA. Any help would be great - section of code below

```
With ActiveWorkbook

                .Sheets(1).Cells(1).PasteSpecial _
                Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:O").AutoFit
                ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter


                Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete
                Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
                Columns(9).EntireColumn.Delete

                    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
                        .FitToPagesWide = 1
                        .FitToPagesTall = False
                        .Orientation = xlLandscape
                        .PrintGridlines = True
                    End With

 End With
    .PrintOut

End Sub
```

Comment: what object are you trying to print? your code snipet is incomplete